# Bootstrap input overflowing modal dialog

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

the input on my modal dialog is overflowing when at full width http://codepen.io/kruts/pen/oLRgkZ

```
 code
```

but when I resize down to small device size it seems to work but I need it to work at full size as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWbPEZ

I've removed the `container` and `row` divs.